# How to compile and set up Sizzle, an open source Sawzall implementation for Hadoop, on Mac OS X?

Tags: hadoop, sizzle

'Sizzle is an open source implementation of the Sawzall programming language designed for interoperation with the Hadoop MapReduce and DFS stack.' https://github.com/anthonyu/Sizzle

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, now I have a successful build on the MBP: https://github.com/anthonyu/Sizzle/issues/closed#issue/1